# Aiokafka library does not consume messages asynchronously

Tags: python, apache-kafka, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to implement Python aiokafka async library and for some reason I can't process the messages asynchronously.

I created async consumer, producer and use the asyncio python library.

#### environment:

```
 python 3.7.2
aiokafka==0.5.1
kafka-python==1.4.3
```

#### Consumer:

```
from aiokafka import AIOKafkaConsumer
import asyncio
import json
import ast

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def consume():
    consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
        "test_topic", loop=loop, bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
    # Get cluster layout and topic/partition allocation
    await consumer.start()
    try:
        async for msg in consumer:
            sleep_time = ast.literal_eval(json.loads(msg.value))
            print('before sleep %s' % sleep_time)
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
            print('after sleep %s' % sleep_time)
    finally:
        await consumer.stop()

loop.run_until_complete(consume())
```

#### Producer:

```
import json
import uuid
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer


class KafkaClient(object):
    def __init__(self, topic_name=None, consume=True):
        """
        Initial consumer and producer for Kafka
        :param topic_name: consumer topic name
        """
        self.topic_name = topic_name
        if topic_name is not None:
            self.kafka_connect(topic_name, source='SOURCE')

        self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
                                      key_serializer=str.encode,
                                      value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf-8'))


    def publish_message(self, topic_name, message, extra_data=None):
        try:
            msg_uid = str(uuid.uuid1())
            self.producer.send(topic_name, value=json.dumps(message))
            self.producer.flush()
            print('Message published [msg_uid]: %s' % msg_uid)
            return True

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            return False

k = KafkaClient()
for i in range(0, 1):
    k.publish_message('test_topic', 5)
    k.publish_message('test_topic', 3)
    k.publish_message('test_topic', 1)
```

#### expected result :

the process will print:

```
before sleep 5
before sleep 3
before sleep 1 
after sleep 1
after sleep 3
after sleep 5
```

#### actual result:

the process prints

```
before sleep 5
after sleep 5
before sleep 3
after sleep 3
before sleep 1 
after sleep 1
```

Answer (score 6):

On its own, `async for` doesn't process a sequence in parallel - it just allows a coroutine to suspend while waiting for the next item to be produced by the async iterable. You can think of it as a series of `await`s on the `__anext__` special method, analogous to ordinary for being a series of calls to `__next__`.

But it's easy enough to spawn tasks that process the messages as they arrive. For example:

```
async def process(msg):
    sleep_time = ast.literal_eval(json.loads(msg.value))
    print('before sleep %s' % sleep_time)
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print('after sleep %s' % sleep_time)

async def consume():
    consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
        "test_topic", loop=loop, bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
    await consumer.start()
    tasks = []
    try:
        async for msg in consumer:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(process(msg))
    finally:
        await consumer.stop()
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: How can we chain this with the manual commit?

Comment: @ElPapi42 I don't know enough about aiokafka to answer that. You might want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @user4815162342 so standard python based kafka consumer library is not  asynchronous in itself?

Comment: @y_159 The library is asynchronous; the asker just had flawed expectations of how `async for` works.

Comment: @user4815162342 but he is using `AIOKafkaConsumer` instead of `KafkaConsumer`.

Comment: @y_159 Oh, I see. I have no personal experience with Python kafka consumer libraries, so you probably want to ask a separate question.

Comment: @user4815162342 will the above code consume the data infinitely, i mean whenever there's some data in the topic, it will consume? Is it like busy waiting at line `async for msg in consumer:`?

Comment: @y_159 I would expect `async for msg in consumer` to consume data infinitely, but not "busy waiting" - I'd expect it to sleep when there are no messages for it to return.